# Reading a .txt file, manipulating it, and pushing it to a .csv in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm sort of new to Ruby, but I can't seem to make this work.

Here's what grocery_list2.txt looks like:

```
beer,  milk,  apples,  bacon
```

and here's what I want returned in the .csv file, but I don't even know where to start to reformat it to look like this...

```
Item 1 -- beer
Item 2 -- milk
Item 3 -- apples
Item 4 -- bacon
```

Here's my code:

```
# reading the grocery list from grocery_list2.txt and splitting at each ","
csv_grocery_list = IO.read("grocery_list2.txt").split(",")

#I want this to open a new CSV file called grocery_list3.csv and put in my grocery list
CSV.open("grocery_list3.csv", "w") do |csv|
csv_grocery_list.each do |item|
    csv << p
 end
end
```

Right now, I can't stop getting errors and it isn't pushing to the CSV.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean `csv << item` ?

Comment: I am confused. The first example to me looks like CSV, while the second one looks like text. Are you trying to read a CSV and then convert it to text?

Comment: I'm trying to print to the CSV text that says "Item 1 -- beer".  I know it's not the normal way to use a CSV, but it's what's being requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. Looks like you're starting out with a bunch of fields on one line, so you need to use split like you're doing to get the items into an array. Next, you open a csv for writing, iterate over your array (with index, so you can have your item numbers), and write that to the new CSV file.

Note: the csv push operation expects a list of columns, even if there's just one.

```
csv_grocery_list = IO.read("grocery_list2.txt").split(",")

CSV.open("grocery_list3.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv_grocery_list.each_with_index do |item, index|
    csv << ["Item #{index + 1} -- #{item}"]
  end
end
```